# Patent DES. 122,019 8/20/40

Tags: patent-infringement, inventorship

My grandfather, Norbert R. Hahn, holds a patent dated 8/20/40 for the mascara brush.  Other information, Des. 122,019.  Can someone help me locate more information regarding this patent?  I hold the actual patent and prototype.

Answer (score 1):

It is for **a** mascara brush not **the** mascara brush. Specifically, as a design patent, it is for the design or "look" pictured. 
[image]

An earlier design of a mascar brush is [D109634](http://www.google.com/patents/USD109634). You can see the patent you referenced on google patents here: [Norbert Halm](http://www.google.com/patents/USD122019). If you are interested it should be possible to order a copy of all of the correspondence between the applicant and the USPTO.